How to overload functions string.byte and string.char to support Unicode UTF-8?
I have custom functions utf8Char (decimal) and utf8Byte(char).
How can I overload the functions string.char(...) and string.byte(s, i, j) in Lua?
Here is an example function what I mean:
local originalStringCharFunction = string.char

-- new function:
function string.char(...)
    local args = {...}
    local chars = {}
    for i, codepoint in ipairs(args) do
        chars[i] = utf8Char(codepoint, originalStringCharFunction)
    end
    return table.concat(chars)
end


What are the types of decimal and char? What do utf8Char and utf8Byte return? Why is there an addtional argument in your example? Lua already has utf8.char and utf8.codes, why not use them?

Lua has no utf8, it's a custom library. Char is string with one or several letters. Decimal is decimal number, positive integer, that has an index code to specific char in unicode.

It has: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5

i hope this is can help you.
local override = {
    char = function()
        -- whatever you want here
        print("Hello")
    end,
    byte = function()
        -- whatever you want here
        print("World")
    end
}

local str = {};
str.__index = string;
string = setmetatable(override, str);

string.char() -- Hello
string.byte() -- World
print(string.lower("HELLO WORLD!")) -- Old string functions still work

